Implication of declaring a class with without sharing keyword and providing its access to guest user
I have created a class with without sharing keyword and I have provided access of this class to guest user profile. This class is being called from a LWC component which is hosted on public support site in salesforce. Inside that class I am accessing a Metadata field to get key. Later I am calling some rest endpoint using this key.
public without sharing class MyRestCalloutClass {

// Declare a static string variable at the class level

  private static List<My_Metadata_Type__mdt> metadataRecord = [Select key from My_Metadata_Type__mdt limit 1];
    private static String bearerToken = metadataRecord.size()>0 ? metadataRecord[0].key : null;

// Method to perform REST callout

public static void makeRestCallout() {
    String endpoint = 'https://api.example.com/endpoint';

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + bearerToken);

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    // Handle response here
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        // Successful response handling
        System.debug('REST callout successful');
        MyCustomObject__c ccTemp = new MyCustomObject__c();
        ccTemp.result = ''+response.getBody();
        insert ccTemp;

    } else {
        // Error handling
        System.debug('REST callout failed with status code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
    }
}}

My query is:
Is there any security implication in using above approach?

One would be that you're prone to flood-like attacks? Script something that clicks the button thousands of times and you'll spam the API endpoint with calls (is the API paid? Would they appreciate being DoS-ed?) and create lots of records for you which can eventually exhaust your storage usage.
Could put a CAPTCHA-like challenge on it.
